# HtmlAgilityPack - wrong automatic conversion of text to date

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am parsing this [webpage](http://www.pxe.cz/Kurzovni-Listek/Oficialni-KL/). In order to get the date of validity, I parse the follwing element

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$main$BCPP$jsdate" type="text" value="7. 9. 2015" id="ctl00_ctl00_main_BCPP_jsdate" class="text hasDatepicker">
```

Firstly, the value of the `input` element is "text", hence "7. 9. 2015" should not be converted to date. Secondly, according to Czech standard, 7.9.2015 is 7th September, 2015. When I read this element using HtmlAgilityPack, I get the following representation

[image]

which unfortunately reads 9th July 2015. The questions are thus:

1. How to forbid the conversion of text value of `input` do date?
2. If the date has to be converted, how can it be converted to the 'right' date?

Any help is much appreciated. 
Daniel

Comment: That "date value" may still mean "september 7th 2015" if the original text is converted correctly to a date and then displayed in a US format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your text to date following way

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("9/7/2015","M.d.yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: @PranavPatel: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" - is this the desired behaviour? Or are you pointing to tryParse the date using "MM/dd/yyyy" and/or "dd.MM.yyyy"?

Comment: @PranavPatel: OK, thanks, changing to "M.d.yyyy" helped.

Comment: sorry for wrong date format, but it good to know that it's working